# ASP.MVC 4, Azure Caching: Error on both local and remote - "role discovery data is unavailable"

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, azure-caching

Whew...ok, been wrestling with this for a while and I can't figure out what is going on.

I am new to Azure caching, but at this point I have read a good bit and I think I have it setup right, but something is obviously wrong so what do I know?

Ok, so first I setup a dedicated caching web worker role using this fine tutorial: http://berniecook.wordpress.com/2013/01/27/distributed-caching-in-azure-cache-worker-role/

I have an ASP.net MVC 4 website that is supposed to be using it.

I have my solution set to multiple starting projects with my cloud caching project set to start first, but no matter what I do, I get the "role discovery data is unavailable".

Sometimes in my output log I get that the Role Environment failed to initialize, but not very often. Most of the time the output log says that is succeeds. Regardless of that, I still get the error above.

I was thinking that maybe the issue was because I was running on local azure storage and compute emulators, so I reconfigured and published the Cloud Service to Azure to see if that helped.

It didn't...

The fun part is that there have been exactly 2 times when it suddenly worked (both when I was working locally). 2 times about of about 100. I didn't do anything different...just ran the debugger and poof, it all worked. This at least lends a bit of credit that it is actually setup correctly.

Needless to say, this is putting a huge damper on my productivity so any advice would be appreciated.

---

**Update**

Ok, I have figured out a workaround of sorts...I have learned that the reason that it consistently failed was because the development web server was holding onto a file which prevented the caching server to launch correctly.

The workaround is to stop the web server each and every time I want to recompile and run the code. This is obviously not ideal, so any ways to make this more reliable would be appreciated.

---

Thanks,
David

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this helps but I find that if I don't shut down the both the storage and compute emulator, I get weird errors, so after doing an F5 and closing the browser down, I manually shut down both emulators